# json file formatting correctly, so LUIS can read the data

Tags: json, botframework, azure-language-understanding, adaptive-cards

My program can read Intents from LUIS correctly and launch other adaptive cards using LUIS Intents, however with this column type, still  is not possible. The Intents am trying to launch here are "user" and "myEmail" in "type": input.text. I know somehow the data field in json must be misplaced, or the title, or id. Here´s the file, any help...?

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "Image",
      "url": "lalala.png",
      "size": "Medium"
    },
    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": 2,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Einloggen",
              "weight": "Bolder",
              "size": "Medium"
            },
            {
              "type": "Input.Text",
              "id": "myName",
              "title": "user",
              "data": "user",
              "placeholder": "Benutzername oder email"
            },
            {
              "type": "Input.Text",
              "id": "myEmail",
              "title": "myEmail",
              "data": "myEmail",
              "placeholder": "Passwort",
              "style": "Email"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Submit"
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Cancel"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: btw the LUIS intents am trying to launch are "myEmail" and "user"

Comment: I would like to help but it's unclear what your issue is. Please edit your question to include an actual question.

Comment: I asked you to include an actual question. Why did you not include an actual question? A question ends with a question mark.

Comment: edited 4 mins ago

Comment: I am asking you to ask an actual question so that we're able to answer it. Putting a question mark at the end of a sentence fragment like "any help..." does not help us help you. We need to know what you're asking in order to help you. Please read the Stack Overflow help documents and apply that knowledge to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: LUIS is a language understanding service. You can't "launch" a LUIS intent, so I presume you mean you have some kind of bot set up to respond to LUIS intents with specific functions and you're trying to call the functions in response to this Adaptive Card's submit actions. There's no reason to call LUIS when you already know what functions you want to call so just leave LUIS out of this. Please provide the relevant bot code and explain what you're trying to do with it and what trouble you're having. https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, didn´t read before https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/  were the problem between action submit and data is better specified.

```
    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": 2,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Einloggen",
              "weight": "Bolder",
              "size": "Medium"
            },
            {
              "type": "Input.Text",
              "id": "myName",
              "title": "user",
              "placeholder": "Benutzername oder email"
            },
            {
              "type": "Input.Text",
              "id": "myEmail",
              "title": "myEmail",
              "placeholder": "Passwort"

            }

          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Submit",
      "data": {
        "myName": true,
        "myEmail": true
      }
    }


  ] }
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm still working on this project, and this json still doesn't work. I just have not time to update the question.

Comment: Please click on the check mark to accept this as your answer and ask a new question when you have the time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure your question because nothing in the adaptive card really relates to LUIS. That said, you must specify a unique id for "remember me" toggle - the current null value won't work.

I'd also recommend the adaptivecards.io designer as a place to validate your cards.
[adaptivecards.io/designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/)

Comment: Updated question and file as well. Intents to work are "user" and "myEmail".